# To post JSON to External System via Visualforce Page usin HTML Form

Tags: visualforce, integration, html, post

enter code here

```
<apex:page standardController="fleet_Car_Set__c" showHeader="true">
<html>

    <object style="height : 1200px;width : 1300px;overflow:hidden;">
    <form id="frm" action="http://XXX/?username=ZZZ_UserName&password=PWD&retUrl={/apex/response}" method="POST">

      //  <input type="hidden" id="username" value="ZZZ_UserName"/>  //Tis input tag not working, so directly passed Username and password in action only.
        // <input type="hidden" id="password" value="PWD"/>
        // <input type="Json" id="JSON" value="('{!fleet_Car_Set__c.JSON_String__c}')"/>---
    </form>
    </object>
    <script>
    alert("Inside Script");
    alert('{!Fleet_Car_Set__c.JSON_String__c}');//---Here we are getting full JSON data, need to post this JSON to External System(http://XXX/).
        document.forms["frm"].submit();
    </script>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

I need to Post JSON data to external System, above is my code I tried, but no luck. Please help me to achive this.

Comment: Basically in salesforce we take rest API help to make callout to external system and pulled/pushed the data in external system. [REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/)

Comment: By including a username and password in your page you are allowing someone who wants to hack direct access to the external system which is usually dangerous. Making the request from the server-side in Apex avoids that problem.

Comment: We will take care of the security part later, as of now I need to Post the JSON to external Url. Not through Apex. Please help me out.

Comment: I am able to submit a GET request. Are you too able to make a GET request and not able to submit a POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the name attribute;

```
<input type="Json" name="JSON" id="JSON" value="{!fleet_Car_Set__c.JSON_String__c}"/>
```

It is working for me when I post a GET request to a url action= "http://localhost:8080/XXX".

**Edit:**

```
value="{!fleet_Car_Set__c.JSON_String__c}"
```

is fine. No need to add extra '' or ()

Comment: the above code works, only mistake was in input Name, that external system was not identifying. Thank you very much for you help:)

Comment: Now I am able to post the JSON with POST request to External System.